# Syncfusion Angular PDF Viewer Control - Passing Headers Along

Tags: angular, syncfusion, pdf-viewer

We use token-authentication on our endpoints and when viewing a PDF I'd like to use the standard [Syncfusion implementation approach](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/pdfviewer/getting-started/) but want to know if it's possible to pass headers along with the request. I've ask the question on their forums but I'm aware that feedback can take a bit long.

I see that its possible with their "[Uploader control implementation](https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/137438/passing-header-with-the-url)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can add Authorization header to the PDF Viewer control’s AJAX request in the sample level.  Kindly include the below code in `ngOnInit()` of TS file,

```
ngOnInit(): void {            
    (<any> XMLHttpRequest).prototype.realSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
    var newSend = function (vData) {      
        this.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer 64565dfgfdsjweiuvbiuyhiueygf');          
        this.realSend(vData);
    };
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = newSend;
}
```

The XMLHttpRequest’s method `setRequestHeader()`, adds custom HTTP headers to the request.

We have created the sample for the same and shared in the following location,
https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/my-app_Authentication1715968051

Please find the below KB link for reference,
https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/10334/how-to-add-anti-forgery-token-to-the-pdfviewercontrol

Please try this and let us know if you have any concerns on this.

Regards,
Akshaya